# What are the rules for automatic arrays wrapping/unwrapping?

Tags: powershell

Consider this code:

```
$a = '[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]'
"Test1"
$a | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.GetType() }
"Test2"
$b = $a | ConvertFrom-Json
$b | ForEach-Object { $_.GetType() }
```

This produces the following output:

```
Test1

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                                       
Test2
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object                                                                                                                      
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Evidently, if we use a temporary variable, whatever is passed down the pipeline is not the same thing that is passed if we do not use one.

I would like to know what the rules that powershell uses for automatic array wrapping / unwrapping are, and if the using a temp var the best course of action if we need to iterate through a json array.

**Update 1**
Logically `ConvertFrom-Json` should return an array with the input given and `ForEach-Object` should iterated on the said array. However in the first test this does not happen. Why?
**Update 2**
Is it possible that it's `ConvertFrom-Json` specific? Like bug/issue?

Comment: You second example was unrolled more than your first. Using the temp allowed that to happen since you used `Foreach-Object` but it was still unrolled at the assignment. _using a temp var the best course of action if we need to iterate through a json array_ That would never be necessary and a touch assertion to make since not all json data is made the same. This would appear status quo to me. Knowing your PowerShell version might be important here.

Comment: @Matt, how it can be unrolled more or less? What was it unrolled from? `ConvertFrom-Json` should return array and `ForEach-Object` should iterate on array, n'est-ce pas? What is being unrolled, when, and exactly to what degree? That's the questions.

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` returned an object which was then unrolled to a two member array each with a single object in it. I will see if I can come up with a more authoritative answer as to what is happening. If it helps look at this `($a | ConvertFrom-Json) | ForEach-Object { $_.GetType() }` that makes the array elements get unrolled since the brackets wont allow the singe array down the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one rule with regard to pipeline items' unwrapping: all arrays and collections written to the pipeline are always getting unwrapped to the items *("unwrapped one level down" or "unwrapped in a non-recursive fashion" would be more correct statement but for the sake of simplicity we are not going to consider nested arrays so far).*

There is still a possibility to override this behavior by using *unary comma* operator:

```
$a = 1,2
$a | ForEach-Object{ $_.GetType() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType

,$a | ForEach-Object{ $_.GetType() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

In the second case Powershell pipeline engine unwrapped `$a` but afterwards the result got wrapped back to array by `,` operator.

As to `ConvertFrom-Json` case I personally believe that its observed behavior is more predictable as it allows you to capture JSON arrays as a whole by default.
If you are interested in the details, the function `Get-WrappedArray` in the code below imitates `ConvertFrom-Json`'s behavior:

```
function Get-WrappedArray {
  Begin   { $result = @() } 
  Process { $result += $_ } 
  End     { ,$result }
}

$a | Get-WrappedArray | ForEach-Object{ $_.GetType() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

$b = $a | Get-WrappedArray
$b | ForEach-Object{ $_.GetType() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

Comment: So your opinion is that `ConvertFrom-Json` is written this way on purpose?

Comment: @Andrew Savinykh Have no idea about intention of the creator, I just wanted to show the details how it might have been done and tell that this is slightly more 'predictable' in my opinion